# Netsuite Bundle Development

Tags: eclipse, netsuite

Is there any way to develop a netsuite bundle using eclipse and deploy on the netsuite site?
Is it compulsory to use the tools that provide by the netsuite for bundle development?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot create a bundle using the eclipse. Eclipse is only an IDE for creating javascripts for faster modification and uploading of scripts.

You can only create bundle from NetSuite and no tools can be used to create one.

Comment: Not only JavaScripts, you can also create Custom Records, Fields, Searches... using XML and the SDF features.

Answer (score 3):

You can create netsuite bundle **only by Bundle Builder in Netsuite** , **period**.
Bundles are packages of customization or configuration objects that can be installed in other NetSuite accounts. The Bundle Builder is available at **Customization > SuiteBundler > Create Bundle** ,
if the SuiteBundler feature is enabled in your account and you have the SuiteBundler permission.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid but there is no such plug-in or tools in eclipse that allows you to create a Netsuite bundle. What only you can do is, you can pull all your suite scripts from `File Cabinet` and then you change your environment and credentials for another account and push your scripts.

> **This will work only for scripts that you pull from filecabinet using eclipse**

Note: You can't just import customized objects, forms & workflows from one account to another with eclipse. Inorder to have a complete set of customized bundle there is no option other than `Netsuite UI` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Bundles can only be created via SuiteBundler as of today. And it is used to move your objects from one account to other.

The same can be achieved via Netsuite SDF via eclipse. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Bundle Builder of Netsuite is the only way to create bundle in Netsuite. You can go to the Bundle Builder from Customization > SuiteBundler > Create Bundle. You must have the SuiteBundler feature enabled in your account in order to get this feature